# can't load jdbc driver class PostgreSQL + NIFI

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-nifi

Start working with Nifi and this is my first exercise.

So trying to put a csv file in a Postgres table. I defined my data base driver as shown in the picture.

The error is:

> can't load jdbc driver class

in my log file I have this message:

```
ERROR [StandardProcessScheduler Thread-1] o.a.n.c.s.StandardControllerServiceNode DBCPConnectionPool[id=c25f8f91-0161-1000-a496-8910832bdbd8] F$
org.apache.nifi.reporting.InitializationException: Can't load Database Driver
        at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getDriverClassLoader(DBCPConnectionPool.java:249)
        at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.onConfigured(DBCPConnectionPool.java:198)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor437.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:137)
        at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:125)
        at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:70)
        at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotation(ReflectionUtils.java:47)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceNode$2.run(StandardControllerServiceNode.java:409)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ClassNotFoundException%3A+org.postgresql.Driver

Comment: i saw some responses and i tried them but i get always the same error

Comment: Can you share your DBCPConnectionPool configuration?

Comment: thank you for your responses! I found the problem :)  I insert a return in the line after the jdbc name

Comment: can you please add your code and POM file to understand it better

Answer (score 3):

The postgres jdbc driver doesn't come packaged with nifi.  You must

1. download the **driver** (jar) e.g. **postgresql-42.2.24.jar**
2. place it in the **nifi/lib** folder
3. **restart** nifi
4. Open your **DBCPConnectionPool** controller service properties
5. Set **Database Driver Class Name** to **org.postgresql.Driver**

Resources

- https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3497/agqka/index.html
- https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-dbcp-service-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool/index.html

Comment: Hi can you please let me know what to do next, I have placed the jar inside lib folder what path should I need to give in the "Database Driver Location(s)" ?

Comment: @ChitrangSharma see my edits above.  Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The asker found the root cause:
I insert a return in the line after the jdbc name